# Schema Stitching resolve conflict by adding prefix

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-tools

So I have this two schemas

Schema1

```
type Permission {
    relation: Relation
}

enum Relation {
    ONE
    TWO
    THREE
}
```

Schema2

```
type Permission {
    relation: Relation
}

enum Relation {
    FOUR
    FIVE
    SIX
}
```

The expect result is something similar to: (but I'm open to different ideas)
The queries I would like to make after the merge are:

```
{
    permissions{
        relation
    }
}
```

And get a result like

```
"permissions": [
  {
    "relation": "ONE"
  },
  {
    "relation": "SIX"
  }
]
```

or

```
"permissions": [
  {
    "relation": "schema1ONE"
  },
  {
    "relation": "schema2SIX"
  }
]
```

And mutations like:

```
mutation{
  createPermission(
    relation: ONE
  ){
    relation
  }
}

mutation{
  createPermission(
    relation: SIX
  ){
    relation
  }
}
```

or

```
mutation{
  createPermission(
    relation: schema1ONE
  ){
    relation
  }
}

mutation{
  createPermission(
    relation: schema2SIX
  ){
    relation
  }
}
```

I'm trying using the `transformSchema` function on graphql-tools but can't quite figure it out correctly:

```
const Schema1 = await getRemoteSchema('schema1_url', 'schema1');
const Schema2 = await getRemoteSchema('schema2_url', 'schema2');

const schemas = [Schema1, Schema2]

const schema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: schemas,
  resolvers: {}
});
```

getRemoteSchema definition

```
export const getRemoteSchema = async (uri: string, schemaName: string): Promise<GraphQLSchema> => {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri, fetch });

  const schema = await introspectSchema(httpLink);

  const executableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema,
    httpLink,
  });

  // transform schema by renaming root fields and types
  const renamedSchema = transformSchema(
    executableSchema,
    [
      new RenameTypes(name => {
        if (name == 'Relation') {
          return schemaName + name
        } else {
          return name
        }
      }),
      // new RenameRootFields((operation, name) => `${schemaName}_${name}`)
    ]
  );

  return renamedSchema;
}
```

I made this glitch https://glitch.com/edit/#!/schema-stitching-conflict
So it's easier to see the problem.

Comment: So for one part is the renaming of the types, but also the joining of the permission types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both `RenameTypes` and `RenameRootFields` transforms, 
`RenameTypes` to transform the typenames

from: `Permission` and `Relation` (The colliding types),

to: `schema1_Permission`, `schema2_Permission`

and: `schema1_Relation`, `schema1_Relation`

`RenameRootFields` to transform the Query names for those types

from: `permission(id: ID!): Permission`

to: `schema1_permission(id: ID!): schema1_Permission` and `schema2_permission(id: ID!): schema2_Permission`

and: `permissions: [Permission]`

to: `schema1_permissions: [schema1_Permission]` and `schema2_permissions: [schema2_Permission]`

The transform would be something like:

```
const {
  makeExecutableSchema,
  addMockFunctionsToSchema,
  transformSchema,
  RenameTypes,
  RenameRootFields
} = require('graphql-tools');

const schema1 = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: `
    type Permission {
      id: ID!
      text: String
      relation: Relation
    }

    type Query {
      permissions: [Permission]
      permission(id: ID!): Permission
    }

    enum Relation {
      ONE
      TWO
      THREE
    }
  `
});

addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema: schema1 });

const renamedSchema1 = transformSchema(
  schema1,
  [
    new RenameTypes(name => {
      if (name == 'Relation' || name == 'Permission') {
        return 'schema1_' + name
      } else {
        return name
      }
    }, { renameBuiltins: false, renameScalars: true }),
    new RenameRootFields((_op, name) => {
      return name.includes('ermission') ? `schema1_${name}` : name
    })
  ]
);
```

references:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms/
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching/

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't see an easy-to-go way to achieve your desired behaviour using **graphql-tools** because in the implementation of `mergeSchemas()` the option `onTypeConflict` was [first deprecated and later removed](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/863), even though it still exists on the public interface. With that option we were able to simply pass a callback that was aware of the conflicting types and their corresponding ASTs.

`transformSchema()` however, as you try to use it, will only rename the enum type names but not the enum values. You will most likely need to implement your own transformation instead of using a pre-defined one to achieve your goals. I'd like to recommend having a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/blob/master/src/transforms/ConvertEnumValues.ts) of `ConvertEnumValues` though. This might give you a better sense of how to walk and manipulate the AST to your needs when implementing your own `Transform`.

For example I'd consider an implementation which keeps track of all `GraphQlEnumTypes` that it has seen and deep merges them, if it encounters a name collision. Either you keep track using variables within module scope or using instance properties in the `Transform`. If you do the latter, don't forget to instantiate it in advance and to pass it to subsequent `tranformSchema()` calls by reference.